# Escape keyword in the handlebar template

Tags: ember.js

I have a collection of objects (`MyApp.instrsController`, an `ArrayController`) and each object has a property called 'action' (a float number), how can I display it using the handlebars template?

Below is the code I've tried:

```
<ul>
{{#each MyApp.instrsController}}
   <li>{{action}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

But since 'action' is a 'keyword', it throws javascript runtime error 'options is undefined'.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually specify that you're looking for a property in the current context by preceding the property name with `this.`:

```
{{this.action}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I still get the same error.

Comment: Hmm... that would work (I *think*) with vanilla handlebars at least... You could use the `unbound` helper, I suppose.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the property name you can use a computed property in your model object, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/4ZQM8/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    <ul>
        {{#each App.controller}}
            <li>{{actionProp}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.Object = Ember.Object.extend({
    actionProp: function() {
        return this.get('action');
    }.property('action')
});


App.controller = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    addObj: function(number) {
        this.pushObject(App.Object.create({
            action: number
        }));
    }
});
```

---

If you don't have a custom model object, you can use a computed property on a CollectionView, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/r6XAc/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item" >
    {{actionProp}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
Ember.CollectionView.create({
    contentBinding: 'App.controller',
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'item',
        actionProp: function(){
            return this.getPath('content.action');
        }.property()
    })
}).append();
```

Answer (score 1):

I seriously suggest that you just change the name of the property. 
You are spending time working on a problem that is not core to your domain.

YAGNI.  KISS.

The biggest lesson to learn in programming is how to get things made and done rather than how to manipulate javascript into not throwing a snit over your use of a reserved keyword.  You will be happier later if you don't have a fragile solution that looks tricky to understanc

Since this is a float, can I suggest you use "actionLevel"?

Answer (score -2):

just use model.property,such as:

```
{{input class="input-xlarge" value=model.content }}
```