# Is there an official list for Handlebars reserved words?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, email-templates

After struggling with a template var named `{{engine.x.y}}`, which was "silently" showing nothing until I changed it for something else such as `{{_engine.x.y}}`, I saw that [other words such as `{{action}}` seemed to be "reserved", with no "escaping" possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10809185/488666)...

Is there any list of such "reserved words" in order to lessen the "surprise factor" ? I couldn't find any.

**EDIT**

- even more strange, when I use `{{engine}}` directly (not `engine.x.y`) it always gets replaced by the string `".hbs"`
- however in my context (Node v4.6 + email-templates + handlebars) `{{action}}` works correctly ([linked problem above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10809185/488666) looks specific to Ember.js)

Comment: I just searched the [handlebars.js source code](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=engine) / [mustache.js source code](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=engine), and oddly I couldn't even find any instances of the word "engine", which is strange. I also looked for any instances of reserved words, and there are results in the handlebars.js source code, but it looks like it is referring to the [globally reserved variables in JS](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=reserved).

Comment: Are you using Ember? I'd hazard a guess that the 'reserved' values are coming from whatever is setting the scope for Handlebars, rather than Handlebars itself.

Comment: @JoeClay you're right, I'm not using ember and using `{{action}}` in my case (Node.js v4.6) works perfectly. Interesting...

Comment: The important question, then - what are you passing as your template's context object?

Comment: @JoeClay Handlebars is used through package `email-templates`: `var EmailTemplate   = require('email-templates').EmailTemplate` then `var emailTemplate = new EmailTemplate(<someDir>);` then `emailTemplate.render(<my object with a .engine property>, function (err, renderedTemplate) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it - the issue isn't with Handlebars (which Josh Crozier found to not reserve any names in the comments above), it's with the `email-templates` library that you're using. The `render` function it uses sets several properties on the object that gets passed as the template context, meaning that if your object contains properties with the same name, they get clobbered.

The relevant line of code in the `email-templates` source can be found [here](https://github.com/crocodilejs/node-email-templates/blob/master/src/template-manager.js#L39), but for the sake of completeness, the properties which get overwritten are:

- `filename` (set to your template's filename)
- `engine` (set to the file extension of the templating engine that's being used)
- `templatePath` (set to the directory that contains your template)

The most obvious solution would be to just change the name, but if that's not an option you may need to [file an issue on their repo](https://github.com/crocodilejs/node-email-templates/blob/master/src/template-manager.js#L39).

Comment: Only 3 "special cases" then... I've been in bad luck there... ^^ Anyway thanks ! Impressed by your quickness and thorough explanations.

Comment: @FrostyZ: No problem! Glad I could help :)